# Voronoi Diagram on Array of Vertices

Tags: python, geopandas, voronoi

I'm trying to create a diagram of a sample map. I feed the x and y vertices of the map into an array, after which I perform a

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import *
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d

#reads shapefile of region
cities = gpd.read_file('belgian_cities.shp')

#plots the cities
cities.plot()

cities.plot(cmap = 'jet')

g = [i for i in cities.geometry]
x,y = g[0].exterior.coords.xy
all_coords = np.dstack((x,y)) ####

for interior in g[0].interiors: # for first feature/row
    x, y = interior.coords.xy
    coords = np.dstack((x,y))
    all_coords = np.append(all_coords, coords, axis=0)

vor = Voronoi(all_coords)
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
plt.show()
```

However, when I run the code, I receive two errors:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
>
> ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 3)

This is my first time working with GeoPandas and Voronoi, so it would be great if anyone could take a look.

Current Result:

[image]

Comment: Please add the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'` problem using dstack and Voronoi.

`np.dstack((x,y))` returns [[[x1, y1],[x2, y2],....]]
note the extra brackes you need to change the line to
`all_coords = np.dstack((x,y))[0]`

I'm not sure about the other error. I did not get it.